# What other tool can substitute for Selenium?

Tags: java, optimization, selenium, size

I have used Selenium to program some web utilities in an embedded system, but after adding the Java runtime the size of the deliverable increases by 30Mb. Is there some other tool that can do the same thing with less?

I am quite happy with it, but the increase in the size feels wrong.

Update: After reading the replies I have realized that HttpClient or HtmlUnit is what I need. Selenium uses HtmlUnit and as I am not testing as such HtmlUnit may be enough.

Since the answer turns me in a different direction am I supposed to close it?

Comment: Sure, but is the 80M actually important? You don't say what you're doing with Selenium, so it's impossible to suggest a substitute other than something like HtmlUnit etc.

Comment: It is for reprogramming some devices on a LAN if the network changes.The current downloadable is 160Mb, adding the JRE and Selenium will make it 190Mb or so.

Comment: That doesn't help; how would we know what you're actually using from Selenium in order to suggest a replacement? And how is 190M - 160M = 80M? If you're just interacting w/ web pages, use HttpClient/HtmlUnit/etc.

Comment: I corrected the 80Mb bit. I will look to HttpClient/HtmlUnit to see how much I can reduce the size

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be including Selenium or your Java-based Selenium test cases in your final deliverable.  Can you find a way to package your final application such that Selenium isn't included?

Comment: Is there some reason not to include it? Selenium is what I found easy and quick to learn.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you're talking about including the Selenium jar files and such in your final .war (or .ear or .sar...) file that is the end-result of your build process.  Selenium is a testing tool; it's something that you use to test your own project, and isn't meant to be something that gets distributed with the Production-level version of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Watij](http://watij.com/) (watir for Java).

But your argument against selenium sounds strange  wre you using it for tests? If so, your runtime shouldn't change. If not, perhaps you are using the wrong thing. You can see HtmlUnit instead.